# HTML form only password input autofill WANTED

Tags: html, forms, input, passwords, autofill

This is my first question and request for help. I put together a domain/subfolder site as a photo album for my family with only static .js go-through from domain index page with password form at the very bottom (that's all the security needed - it's photos of a newborn, not a banking account). I would like for my parents not to have to type in the password each time when entering the photo album. However, I am not able make it autofill the password for me. I have tried workaround (** **added** **) not only without any success but also messing my .js go-through. Any suggestions?

https://vilem.fun/

```
<div>
    <form id="login-form">
    **<input type="password" name="username" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Single User" style="display: none;">**
    <input type="password" name="token" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password Here" **autocomplete="current-password"**>
    <input type="submit" value="Family photoalbum" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
    <p id="login-error-msg">&nbsp;<br>Wrong Password<br>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this:

autocomplete="on"
instead of
autocomplete="current-password"

```html
<div>
    <form id="login-form">
        <input type="password" name="username" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Single User" style="display: none;">
        <input type="password" name="token" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password Here" autocomplete="on">
        <input type="submit" value="Family photoalbum" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
        <p id="login-error-msg">&nbsp;<br>Wrong Password<br>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not autofilling with chrome. I tried couple more variants like input type=text/hidden with fixed value and so on, but no result. I realized chrome is suggesting saving password manually (key symbol) but only when signed in. Using Edge, working solution enabling saving the password and subsequently autofilling it:

Comment: <div> <form id="login-form"> <input type="hidden" name="user" id="username-field" class="login-form-field" value="Single user"> <input type="password" name="token" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password here" autocomplete="on"> <input type="submit" value="Family photoalbum" id="login-form-submit"> </form> <div id="login-error-msg-holder"> <p id="login-error-msg">Wrong password</p> </div> </div>

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <form id="login-form" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password Here">
    <input type="submit" value="Family photoalbum" id="login-form-submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
    <p id="login-error-msg">&nbsp;<br>Wrong Password<br>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the browser doesn't recognize it, because you don't have a "username" field

Comment: Thanks, see my comments above.